# Log4j log into multiple files

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I tried to log into mutliple files, but it doesn't work..

Here is the configuration

```
log4j.logger.org.net.portal=DEBUG, stdout, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/default.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern="[%t] %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %l - %m%n"

log4j.appender.secondFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.secondFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.secondFile.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.secondFile.File=C:/secondfile.log
log4j.appender.secondFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.secondFile.layout.ConversionPattern="[%t] %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %l - %m%n"

log4j.additivity.myLogger=false
log4j.logger.myLogger=DEBUG, secondFile
```

In code I'm getting logger like:

```
 private static final Logger loggerSmsOrdering = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
```

and there is nothing in second file.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add secondFile to logger
log4j.logger.org.net.portal=DEBUG, stdout, file, secondFile

Comment: no, definitely not. then I will have same stuff in file and in secondFile. I tried now in separate project and it is working. I am really curious what is wrong there.

Comment: Ok so the origin configuration is complete ok. There was special project setup, which reset log4j configuration and setup new one. So it is explanation, why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can modify like below

```
    log4j.rootLogger =DEBUG,file,secondFile

    log4j.category.myLogger=DEBUG,file 
    log4j.additivity.myLogger=false


    log4j.category.myLogger=DEBUG,secondFile
    log4j.additivity.myLogger=false

    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
    log4j.appender.file.Threshold=DEBUG
    log4j.appender.file.File=C:/default.log
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern="[%t] %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %l - %m%n"

    log4j.appender.secondFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.secondFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
    log4j.appender.secondFile.Threshold=DEBUG
    log4j.appender.secondFile.File=C:/secondfile.log
    log4j.appender.secondFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.secondFile.layout.ConversionPattern="[%t] %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %l - %m%n"
```